# Disable animation on md-tabs, angularjs material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The animation when switching tabs is so laggy. Makes my entire application unusable. A true show-stopper.

I've read many questions on the topic. Is it really total impossible to remove this animation?

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add this line of css to disabled it: ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/a09Jj3GAzbiw1jfhldct?p=preview))

```
/* This will disable the panel animation */
md-tabs [role="tabpanel"] {
    transition: none;
}

/* This will disable the `ink-bar` animation (border-bottom of selected tab) */
md-tabs md-ink-bar {
  transition: none;
}
```

---

Additionally, if you want to hide/remove the `ink-bar` (use `display: none` instead `transition: none`) and add custom style the selected tab...

```
md-tabs .md-active {
   font-weight: bold;
   /* Add your custom css styles to selected tab here */
}
```

** *Tested and worked from angularjs-material versions > 1.0.0*

Comment: What a relief. Thank you!